# How come I'm getting a CSS loading error in Django with just a minor difference in path name?

Tags: css, django, django-urls

Just to give a brief background on the issue, I set up a simple ticketing system. Version I used for Django is 3.0.7, whereas Python is 3.7. I used both bootstrap as my header and crispy forms to design the forms. Also, if it might help, I used all-auth. I placed the static configuration within my settings.py to make sure Django finds it within the directory:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Then loaded the following within my templates:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
```

This would load the pages properly. I didn't come across any issues. Now this is where I found an interesting situations. When I used this path for editing forms in urls.py:

```
path('edit/ticket/<int:pk>', ticketEditView, name='edit_ticket'),
```

The page loaded with all the details but the CSS did not load properly. An error of '"GET /edit/static/css/_base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3229"' popped up.

When I replaced the path with the one below, everything seemed to work properly.

```
path('edit/<int:pk>', ticketEditView, name='edit_ticket'),
```

I want to know the difference of the path in urls.py. Why it reacted the way it reacted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you maybe forget to put the tag `{% load static %}` in the respective template?

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I initially didn't use a template tag for static. I used a directory instead "../static/css/core_base.css." Although I find it odd that it worked for other pages. I'm curious to what happened. I want to know why it reacted that way.